# Understanding an example in Israel Gohberg pg.54.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Here is the example:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

**My questions are:**

1-I did not understand the last two paragraphs, could anyone explain them for me, please? do they mean that the identity operator is unbounded in that kind of operators?

2-Does the last paragraph means that so the proof just before the two paragraphs is valid even if we do not have condition (1)?

Comment: 1-If I am not wrong what he's saying is that even though the identity operator is bounded it doesn't satisfy the condition (1). 2- he means that there are not necessary or sufficient conditions implying the entries of a matrix to conclude whether it's a bounded operator or not

Comment: @RScrlli does that means that those type of matrices are still bounded even if they do not satisfy condition (1)? but the proof requires that condition(1) must also be satisfied for them to be bounded.

Comment: Also, so how do we know that the identity operator is bounded? is there a proof for this without using condition(1)? @RScrlli

Comment: @RScrlli I believe that condition(1) is required for the above proof of boundedness to be correct ..... am I correct?

Comment: By definition a bounded linear operator "is a linear transformation $L$ between normed vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ for which the ratio of the norm of $L(v)$ to that of $v$ is bounded above by the same number, over all non-zero vectors $v$ in $X$". (see Wikipedia) Hence is clear that the identity operator is indeed bounded (the ratio would be equal to $1$). Nonetheless the identity operator does not satisfy condition $(1)$

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "those types of matrices", what he is telling you is that even if an operator does not satisfy the condition $(1)$ it could be still be bounded, and that there are no general necessary/sufficient conditions for an operator to be bounded

Comment: I mean by "Those types of matrices " the certain infinite matrices that the book is speaking about. @RScrlli ...... so the proof above the 2 paragraphs is proving what?

Comment: Does that mean@RScrlli in those types of matrices we can not calculate the norm?

Comment: Yes, it means that you cannot estimate the norm (cause the bound would be infinity) but still the operator may be bounded.

Comment: So condition$(1)$ is required to prove that those type of matrices is bounded but it is not required to prove that the identity is bounded .... am I correct? @RScrlli